# is true that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(-1)^n=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, pi

Is true that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(-1)^n=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$? (where $B_n$is the Bernoulli number)

If this is true, how can I prove it?

Comment: More simply, $\frac12+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty B_{2n}$. Of course, you know that the actual sum is divergent, but you are asking for a particular regularization.

Comment: this sum is divergent ?

Comment: Well, you can re-express the sum as $$\frac12-2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k (2k)! \zeta(2k)}{(2\pi)^{2k}}$$ where we used the relationship between Riemann's function and the Bernoulli numbers, and you should now see why it is divergent as it stands. But, again, maybe it can be regularized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the even Bernoulli numbers
grow as
$B_{2n}
\approx 4\sqrt{\pi n}(n/(e\pi))^{2n}
$,
the sum diverges pretty violently.

I will try something else
to try to assign a value.

Since
$\frac{x}{e^x-1}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_n x^n}{n!}
$,

we can try
a standard "trick"
to get rid of the
$n!$ in the denominator:
multiply by $e^{-xt}$
and integrate from
$0$ to $\infty$.

The RHS becomes

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{\infty} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-xt}\frac{B_n x^n}{n!} dx
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}\frac{B_n x^n}{n!} dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n }{n!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}x^n dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n }{t^nn!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-xt}(xt)^n dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n }{t^{n+1}n!} \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}(x)^n dx\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} B_n t^{-n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

The LHS becomes
$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{xe^{-xt}}{e^x-1}dx
$.
If we put
$t=-1$,
which will make the
RHS what we want,
this becomes
$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{xe^{x}}{e^x-1}dx
$.
Unfortunately,
this integral diverges.

However,
putting the indefinite integral
into Wolfy,
it says 
that the indefinite integral
is
$\int (x e^x)/(e^x-1) dx 
= Li_2(e^x)+x \log(1-e^x)
$
(where
$Li_2$
is the dilogarithm)
and
that the expansion
about
$x=0$
is
$\text{(an imaginary expression)}+(\pi^2/6+x+O(x^2))
$
and
the expansion about
$x = \infty$
is
$x \log(1-e^x)-\pi^2/6
$.

These give *some* justification
for thinking that
your value
might has some validity
for some method
of summing divergent series.

Comment: thank you. I found this expression from the integral of $\frac {ln(1-x)}{x}$ in $[0,1]$ that is $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ (if you make the replacement $1-x = e^-u$ and make some algebraic operations you can find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(-1)^n$).

Comment: @Herick, you really should have included that information in your original question. What you did is to convert a convergent improper integral into a series that is formally divergent, but regularizable.